# Difficulty forming a regular expression

Tags: swift, regex, nsregularexpression

I'm trying to check a string to make sure that it only contains lowercase and uppercased letters, the digits 0-9, underscores, dashes and periods.

The regular expression I've been using for letter, numbers, underscores and dashes works fine and is this:

"[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]"

I'm having difficulty adding the check for spaces and periods though.

I've tried:

"[^a-zA-Z0-9_- ]"  (added a space after the dash)
"[^a-zA-Z0-9_-\s\.]" (trying to escape a white space character)

I've also tried putting the \s and \. outside of the main block and also in blocks of their own.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hyphen (representing the character) must be at the beginning or at the end of the (negating) character class.

Inside a character class the period is a normal character, it doesn't need to be escaped.

```
let pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9_. -]+"
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about adding characters which have a special meaning: you forgot the hyphen.
I think that this is what you are looking for:

```
"[\^ a-zA-Z0-9_,\.\-]"
```

Comment: As I said in my post, this does work for allowing letters, digits and underscores and dashes: `[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]`   I'm also pretty sure that anything that needs escaping in  the regex expression needs to be double escaped in the Swift string, right?